# How do I find what files use a specific function or file in a Node project, using VSCode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm working with a Node project using VSCode. I'd like to be able to follow the tree upwards from functions/files at a lower level. That is, if I have an exported function `doSomething` in file `dosomething.js`, I'd like to see what code calls this function, and/or see what code requires this file.

```
// index.js

const { doSomething } = require('./tricky-stuff')




// tricky-stuff.js

const doSomething = function() {}

module.exports = {doSomething}
```

If I'm browsing `tricky-stuff.js`, is there a built-in feature to VSCode that allows me to see usages of either the function `doSomething` or where the file `tricky-stuff.js` is required/imported, so that it would show me the file `index.js` in this case (as well as perhaps other files where `tricky-stuff` is used)?  Is there any extension? I seem to recall that WebStorm could do this, but I can't remember.  (I know I could search for strings, but that seems inelegant).

Answer (score 1):

I think it largely depends on how much VScode knows about your code, via the TypeScript language service or JSDoc comments etc...

Typically you can right click on a function and select the `peek all references` or `find all references` options:

[image]

In this case, it will show you all the places where that function is called or referenced.

Comment: I tried 'peek references' but it doesn't work for me: the code I have is exporting anonymous functions, one per module.  Is there any way to simply see where the file is included?  I'm afraid the code (which I didn't write) has no Typescript references, nor JSDoc comments.

Comment: hmm for that, im not sure if there is a more elegant solution than running a search on the codebase